# Making Daughterboard Symbol and Footprint With Multiple B2B connectors

Tags: footprint, allegro

I am using Allegro/OrCAD.

Suppose I have a PCB module like the one below, which contains multiple B2B connectors and is meant to mount to be plugged into a larger PCB:

[image: s]

Each B2B connector has its own footprint on its own (when used individually). However, in this case, both need to be associated to the same component symbol with a fixed relative positions.

Now, I could make a completely unique footprint dedicated to this component symbol, but it would be convenient to be able to make use of the footprints for the individual B2B connectors.

I do not believe there is a way to have a schematic symbol associate with multiple footprints (or multiple instances of the same footprint). But is there a way to make a "super footprint" that internally uses the footprints of the individual B2B connectors?

If there is, that also raises the issue of how to associate pin numbers between symbol and footprint since the same pin number would appear multiple times in both the symbol and the footprint since the individual B2B connectors appear multiple times.

Are footprints and symbols just the wrong approach to this? Is this something for hierarchical design instead? As in:

1. make a schematic with the symbols for the B2B connectors, and turn that into a block.
2. Then export that netlist into the PCB layout and properly space the B2B connector footprints.
3. Then somehow turn that PCB layout into a block or footprint that can be dropped into other designs?

Comment: This is interesting, because not only do I run into this same problem but it would be useful in other areas.  I have 'stock' layouts I use for certain things (power supplies for example), and being able to use 1 'footprint' to drop that whole section down would be nice.  Currently the only method I am aware of is to just do it at layout-time and have good notes on the spacings.

Comment: @evildemonic I feel there must be a way to drop entire pre-routed layers in (or maybe not? since there are so many more parameters involved and what happens if the parent settings don't match the child? Like layer count? And would it be static or dynamic? i.e. what if you need to tweak things a bit in the parent to get around mounting holes, etc.). That seems even more mysterious than having schematic blocks. I am pretty sure "hierarchical" is the right term for schematics, but I can't even find the equivalent term for PCB layouts.

Comment: "I do not believe there is a way to have a schematic symbol associate with multiple footprints (or multiple instances of the same footprint)".  That's my experience also.  When a part is added to a schematic, from the schematic tool's library (note, we have dedicated person or multiple people to make new symbols), that part includes both the schematic symbol and the footprint.  Each physical part type (footprint) has a unique part library name.

Comment: fill out this webpage ... https://www.orcad.com/about/contact-us

Comment: @jsotola They're pretty tight lipped unless you are paying for an ongoing subscription, except for how much they press for you to get a subscription.

Comment: let me first say that i know nothing about OrCAD ... i am thinking that there may be some way to script the connector placement or a way to record a macro that does the placement